# How can I disable dark mode for all UIViewControllers without using Any BaseUIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

I read Apple Article for disable Dark Mode because I need disable for my all UIViewController and i haven't any BaseUIViewController.

How can I disable Dark Mode for all UIViewController without using any BaseUIViewController? I don't want to write the following code over and over again.

Is there a solution to this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Always adopt a light interface style.    
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

Comment: @Fogmeister for instance to allow incremental implementation of dark mode support. If you force your app to use light mode, you can release your app with partial support to dark mode without users seeing a flawed UX.

Comment: All screen haven't support dark mode. I need to spend time for support dark mode and i don't have much time. @fogmeister

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can force light/dark mode in your whole application regardless of the user's settings by adding the key `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to your `Info.plist` file and setting its value to either Light or Dark.

Comment: UIUserInterfaceStyle light is blocked when updating/uploading your app now. It gets flagged as an invalid plist entry. (Invalid plist key)

Comment: Is there a way to do this in code

Comment: @BradThomas there's no way to do it in code for the whole app, you need to do it for each VC one-by-one as shown in the question or you can do it for a whole `UIWindow` using the same property

Comment: Try this is your AppDelegate.
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}